# Open a rendered Email in Chatter automatically

Tags: lightning-web-components, chatter

We want to click on a button in an lwc an automatically open an already rendered emailtemplate in the chatter email tab without clicking the "insert Template" button:
[image]

I am already able to render the template in a preview window in my lwc, but one requirement is to be able to edit and send the rendered email, with the full functionality of the chatter component.

Background:
the rendered email contains data, formatted as a table, retrieved through a manual process startet in the lwc.

Another viable solution would be to automatically copy the email to the clipboard, when I copy the rendered email via my lwc controller, it is pasted as a plain text, even though the table can be copied manually with mouse + ctrl + c.

document.execCommand('copy');
only seems to copy plain text and the clipboard api does not seem to work in this context.